# Crawler crawls only top level address

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-administration

When I run a full crawl shows only 7 items with 0 errors. instead of crawling the entire web application it only crawls top URL.

I have already checked IIS Response header for MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices. Content source is defined as local sharepoint site with start address as sts4://mydomain.domain.local and https://mydomain.domain.local. Crawl rule is also defined to include every thing under sts4s://mydomain.domain.local/*.  Please help
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a hard struggle, the solution found was very simple. I was writing fully qualified domain name in the start address of content source like sts4s://abc.xyz.local. Whereas I should have written it like sts4s://abc